# Grocery Crud url redirection via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am trying to use a custom redirect on grocery crud on the save button from the edit screen. I can successfully redirect using the URL fragment like the example below:

```
$the_catalogue_id = $this->uri->segment(count($this->uri->segments));    
$this->grocery_crud->set_lang_string('update_success_message',
             'Your data has been successfully stored into the database.<br/>Please wait while you are redirecting to the list page.
             <script type="text/javascript">
              window.location = "'.base_url('catalogues/edit').'/'.$the_catalogue_id.'";
             </script>
             <div style="display:none">'
        );
```

I now need to add the window.location.hash to the end of the redirect URL, but can't seem to get it to work. This is what i have so far:

```
$this->grocery_crud->set_lang_string('update_success_message',
         'Your data has been successfully stored into the database.<br/>Please wait while you are redirecting to the list page.
         <script type="text/javascript">
         var thehash = window.location.hash
          window.location = "'.base_url('catalogues/edit').'/'.$the_catalogue_id.'"#"+thehash";
         </script>
         <div style="display:none">'
    );
```

How do I add the hash variable to the end of the redirect URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quotes from `"+thehash"` .

The concatenation operator and a variable should not be in double quotes in the produced javascript.

```
   var thehash = window.location.hash;
   window.location = "'.base_url('catalogues/edit').'/'.$the_catalogue_id.'#"+thehash;
```